# Try to use "Virtual populate" with Mongoose 7 , but couldn't map any data

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I use Mongoose.js in Express.js, and try to use "Virtual populate" function.
I have two collections, which are "**Room**" and "**Order**", and their definitions are like the following codes.

```
const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
    roomNumbers: [
      {
        number: Number
      },
    ],
  }
);
export default mongoose.model("Room", RoomSchema);

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: String, required: true }, 
    roomNumberId: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Room",
      },
    ]   
  },
  {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  }
);
OrderSchema.virtual("roomNumberList", {
  ref: "Room",
  localField: "roomNumberId", 
  foreignField: "roomNumbers",
});
export default mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

My target is to use **userId** of **Order** collection, to populate the **name** of **roomNumbers** of **Room** collection.
So, my accessing data process is:

```
export const getAllOrdersByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const ordersList = await Order.find({ userId: userId })
      .populate("roomNumberList") 
      .exec();
    console.log(ordersList);
    res.status(200).json(ordersList);
  } catch (error) {
    next(errorMessage(500, "Server error", error));
  }
}
```

However, the json result is:

```json
{
    _id: new ObjectId("64b70c60d6048e2881099496"),
    userId: '6478efd33cc47792f3ce6bc9',
    roomNumberId: [
      new ObjectId("6495c7caef3162cf3e2634bd"),
      new ObjectId("6495c7d3ef3162cf3e2634c2"),
      new ObjectId("6495c7d7ef3162cf3e2634c7")
    ],
    createdAt: 2023-07-18T22:04:16.178Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-07-18T22:04:16.178Z,
    __v: 0,
    roomNumberList: [],
    id: '64b70c60d6048e2881099496'
  }
```

The **roomNumberList** part of the result json is empty....
I spent days to search possible answers but could not find it.
Please help give some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
First of all, I added "mongoose debug" setting for showing the detail of how MongoDB works, like

```
mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
  console.log(`${collectionName}.${method}`, JSON.stringify(query), doc);
});
```

Then, I found out that MongoDB did not use "roomNumbers._id" of **Room** collection to map **Order** collection.
So, I changed my foreignField to **foreignField: "roomNumbers._id"**, like

```
OrderSchema.virtual("roomNumberList", {
  ref: "Room",
  localField: "roomNumberId", //It is any field of the current collection.
  foreignField: "roomNumbers._id", //It is any field of the collection from which we want to populate the document.
});
```